# How do I covert the decimal places of a double to a string?

Tags: c#, string, math, int, double

I have 4 examples:

```
double a = 1.05;
double b = 0.000056;
double c = 0.7812;
double d = 1.2;
```

What I want to do is first find how many place values there are.
in this case

```
int inta = 2;
int intb = 6;
int intc = 4;
int intd = 1;
```

Then I want to create a string with "0" representing those digits. this is for a ToString()

```
string stra = ".00";
string strb = ".000000";
string strc = ".0000";
string strd = ".0";
```

So the only thing I have is a double. I need the place value, then how to create the string.

Comment: How about: convert the numbers to a string of a very long length (like 10 decimal positions). Then delete all leading digits (until the dot). Then delete all trailing zeros.

Comment: @Flydog57 Problem with that is that different values `a != b` can have the same string representation, example [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61671134/how-do-i-covert-the-decimal-places-of-a-double-to-a-string/61671210?noredirect=1#comment109089960_61671301), and this happens even if you look at 17 digits which is the maximum number of reliable significant digits for the `double` type.

Comment: I read "decimal" in the title and had `decimal` in my head.  Yeah, nothing's going to work with with `double`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert the double to a string, then get the substring:

```
double a = 1.05;

// Convert to string
string aString = a.ToString();

// Get substring
string result = aString.Substring(aString.LastIndexOf('.'));

// Get number of decimals
int numDecimals = result.Length - 1;

// Create string based on decimal count
string zeroString = ".";
for (int i = 0; i < numDecimals; i++) {
   zeroString += "0";
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.WriteLine(numDecimals);
Console.WriteLine(zeroString);
// .05
// 2
// .00
```

** To ensure this works for all cultures and not only those who utilize '.' as the decimal separator, you could replace:

`LastIndexOf('.')`

with

`LastIndexOf(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator)`

(Thanks @John)

Comment: This won't work for all cultures!

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. How do then create a new string with ".00"?

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith , no it won't. However judging by the question I presume his code will only be running under cultures containing a '.' for decimals.
I've edited my answer to contain a warning

Comment: Rather than hard-coding it, when not use `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator` or `Sytem.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator`?

Comment: @lakersfan I have updated the answer to include the ".00" string

Comment: @John I have updated the answer to include your compatibility suggestion

Comment: @retryW This will work most of the time, but not all the time (and in fact *cannot* work all the time, as I argued in my post). Change the first line to `double a = 0.2999999999999999;` for example, and you'll get `result = .3` and numDecimals = 1` even though `a == 0.3` evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Doubles don't represent all base-10 fractions accurately. Instead you should use the decimal type.

```cs
decimal a = 1.05;
decimal b = 0.000056;
decimal c = 0.7812;
decimal d = 1.2;
decimal e = 1.456000;

a.ToString() == "1.05"
b.ToString() == "0.000056"
c.ToString() == "0.7812"
d.ToString() == "1.2"
e.ToString() == "1.456000"

public static decimal Normalise(this decimal value) => value / 1.000000000000000000000000000000000m;

e.Normalise().ToString() == "1.456"
```

Comment: Right. For example, (double)0.1m == 3602879701896397 / 36028797018963968.

Comment: The point about double vs decimal may be accurate, but this does not answer the question. It should have been a comment.

Comment: @Herohtar It so happens that I just posted another (non-)answer where I contend that there exists no "right" answer to the question as stated.

Answer (score 0):

I am of the opinion that the problem is ill posed. Specifically, this part:

> first find how many [decimal] place values there are

The number of decimal digits is a matter of representation, not an intrinsic property of the number. When writing `double a = 0.3;` what gets stored into variable `a` is the double precision value which is closest to the exact decimal 0.3. That value is close to 0.3, but not identical to 0.3 simply because IEEE-754 is binary based and `0.3` is a non-terminating binary fraction. But, once assigned, variable `a` has no memory of where it came from, or whether the source code had it as `double a = 0.3;` vs. `double a = 0.29999999999999999;`.

Consider the following snippet:

```
double a = 0.3;
double b = 0.2999999999999999;
double c = 0.29999999999999999;
Console.WriteLine("a = {0}, b = {1}, c = {2}, a==b = {3}, b==c = {4}, a==c = {5}", a, b, c, a==b, b==c, a==c);
```

The output is:

```
a = 0.3, b = 0.3, c = 0.3, a==b = False, b==c = False, a==c = True
```

What this shows is that variables `a` and `c` compare equal i.e. they hold the *exact* same value, yet one was defined with 1 decimal digit while the other one with 17 decimal digits. Point being that it does not make sense to speak of the number of decimal places associated with a floating point *value* because, as this example shows, the same value can have different representations with different numbers of decimal places..

As a side comment, the above also shows that `b` and `c` are different values, even though they differ only in the 17th decimal position. This is consistent with the `double` type having [between 15 and 17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) significant decimal digits, which is why the 16th and 17th digits cannot be ignored in general.